# Python PLY parser : how can I handle unknown value to simplify an equation?

Tags: python, parsing, ply

I'm creating a calculator using PLY and I want to be able to simplify equations.

Let say from this `x + x - 42 / 2` to `2x - 21`

I already have the 'classic' rules for operations :

```py
def p_operations(p): 
    """ expression : sixth
    sixth : fifth
    fifth : fourth
    fourth : third
    third : second
    second : first
    first : NUMBER
    """
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_plus(p):
    """ fifth : fifth '+' fourth """
    p[0] = p[1] + p[3]

def p_minus(p):
    """ fifth : fifth '-' fourth """
    p[0] = p[1] - p[3]

def p_implicit_times(p):
    """ fourth : fourth second """
    p[0] = p[1] * p[2]

def p_times(p):
    """ fourth : fourth '*' third """
    p[0] = p[1] * p[3]

def p_divide(p):
    """ fourth : fourth '/' third """
    p[0] = p[1] / p[3]

def p_modulo(p):
    """ fourth : fourth '%' third """
    p[0] = p[1] % p[3]

def p_floor_divide(p):
    """ fourth : fourth FLOORDIV third """
    p[0] = p[1] // p[3]

def p_unary_minus(p):
    """ third : '-' third """
    p[0] = -p[2]

def p_power(p):
    """ second : first '^' third """
    p[0] = p[1] ** p[3]

def p_paren(p):
    """ first : '(' expression ')' """
    p[0] = p[2]
```

Should I create a special class for unknown numbers or is there a better way in Python ?

Comment: "Unknown numbers" as in variables? Yes, if you want to allow variables in the input, you should have a rule that matches them.

Comment: You're going to need to come up with a way to represent equations, not just variables. Time to start learning about ASTs.

Comment: @sepp2k : "Unknown numbers" NOT as in variables, because a variable holds a known value which is not my case. At this point, I don't want to find the solution to the equation, but only to simplify it, conserving the value unknown and represented by a letter.

Comment: @rici : I understand how to parse my equation to create a AST but how can I interpret it for simplifying the equation ? Do you have any ressources on that topic ? I don't understand how an unknown value can be added to a number (x + 3) for example. What value p[0] should take after a such operation ?

Comment: @cuzureau: it should take the value of a node in the AST, whatever that might look like. ( An `ASTNode` object, I suppose :-) ). Simplifying the equation is trickier; about all you can do is apply heuristics. There are lots and lots of academic papers on the subject dating back to the 60s at least; hopefully you have access to an academic library to help you get through the paywalls. That research is the basis for the popular symbolic computation apps.

Comment: @rici : Ok thanks for the advice, I realized "symbolic computation" was the term that I was looking for. I also saw that the sympy library does what I want to implement by myself.